# set new value depending on another table value trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

What I am trying is to set a new value depending on the value from another table. This is a BEFORE UPDATE trigger. I need to set a new.amount in "webs" table depending on the value of percent column from table "webTransactions". If percent = 30.00 then new amount must change from whatever to 0.00. What I tried so far but is giving me error:

```
if new.type=9 and new.referenceId=0 then set new.amount=0.00 where (SELECT * FROM webs s JOIN webTransactions r ON r.webId = s.id WHERE s.percent = 30.00);
```

Anyone can help to make this trigger run?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
UPDATE websTransactions
SET amount= CASE
WHEN type=9 AND referenceId=0 THEN 0.00
ELSE amount
END
WHERE key IN   
(SELECT key FROM webs s JOIN webTransactions r ON r.webId = s.id 
WHERE s.percent = 30.00)
```

**replace  `key` with the primary key of websTransactions**

Comment: Hi Faby, thank you for your reply, this is missing the percent value from the table webTransactions, how do I condition the value from percent into the new.amount from websTransactions table?

Comment: I've added the where part of the query, Let me know if now fits your question.

Comment: I was checking but something is missing, for you to understand: percent belongs to table webs, and amount belongs to websTransactions table. How can that be added?

Comment: I am not sure why but is giving me error in "where key in..."

Comment: KEY is a preserved word

Comment: @Gervs I have used key and write to change Key with the column name of the primary key (now it's in bold)

Comment: @mikeys you shoul replace key with the primary column name of the table. E.g if the primary key is Id replace key with Id (look that it is present twice in the query)

Comment: @faby maybe you should also mention that this is a standalone query, because if you execute this in before update trigger it may have no effect (since the update will still be performed with the original values.

Comment: Hi, I am still trying this, so as Gervs commented this is a before update, I have this so far but is still giving me error: SET new.amount= CASE
WHEN new.type=9 AND new.referenceId=0 THEN 0.00
ELSE amount END
WHERE id IN   
(SELECT id FROM webs s JOIN webTransactions r ON r.webId = s.id 
WHERE s.percent = 30.00);

Comment: mikeys which error do you get? @Gervs you're right, this is a standalone query and maybe it's not appropriate for before update trigger. I'll update my answer if it doesn't work tomorrow. Now I'm on mobile and I can't code. I'm sorry if it doesn't help you

Comment: Hi Faby, error like theres something still wrong starting in "where id in.." Hopefully you understand what Im trying to get, as maybe in first instance my first query was wrong. What Im trying is a before update trigger, in where the new.amount from table webs gets the value depending on the value from percent column of websTransactions table. Also take note that Webs.Id= websTransactions.webId. Thank you

Comment: I could solve it! I used this: (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM web ..... Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to to use some more efficient code, triggers are a sort of stored routines so program them that way. Also, it's not neccesary to join the table you're updating in a subquery.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER amount_check BEFORE UPDATE ON webs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.type=9 and NEW.referenceId=0 THEN
        SET @percent := (SELECT percent
                     FROM webTransactions
                     WHERE webId = OLD.id);
        IF @percent = 33.00 THEN
            NEW.amount = 0
        END IF;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```